# Proper web redirection with JS window.open call

Tags: asp.net

On a testing server my URL= 
http:
//scantdev04:8086/ActivityReport.aspx

I want to prefill a new URL with query data and pass it to the new url:

string sUrl = sRelativePath + "?Organization=" + sOrganization
                                        + "&&StartDate=" + sStartDate
                                        + "&&EndDate=" + endDate;

string displayScript = "" +
        "window.open('" + sUrl + "', 'DisplayReport', " +
        "'width=1200, height=800, toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes')" +
        "";

Pretty straight forward.

On dev box, localhost, it is all good.

But in test, the URL spits out like:
http://www.displayreport.aspx/?Organization=Correctional%20Alternatives,%20Inc&&StartDate=09-01-2009&&EndDate=10/6/2009%2012:00:00%20AM

How do I fix the www. that is now there and repeat the "http://scantdev04:8086/"

I would rather not push this to the web.config but will if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your `sRelativePath` string come from?

Answer (score 0):

Found this and it seems to work:

old version:
string sRelativePath = Request.ApplicationPath + "/DisplayReport.aspx";

Now changed to :
string sRelativePath = GetWebAppRoot() + "/DisplayReport.aspx";

GetWebRoot() :
string host = (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsDefaultPort) ?

```
       HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host : HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;

   host = String.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, host);

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath == "/")

         return host;

    else

     return host + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```